# Object that contains Field Level Permissions for a Profile

Tags: field-level-security

I would like to bulk update the field level access for multiple profiles and multiple fields.

What is the name of the sObject that contains field level permissions by profile?  "FieldPermissions" plays this role for Permission Sets object, but what is the equivalent object for Profiles?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing, FieldPermissions. Each Profile has a "phantom" PermissionSet assigned to it (found by querying `SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE ParentId = :someProfileId`). Updating this object or its related objects has the same effect as updating the profile.